# Dynamic mysql query with IN param

Tags: mysql, sql

```
 1   USE test;

 2   DELIMITER $$
 3   CREATE  PROCEDURE `SP_TEST_1`(
 4      IN `p_criteria` VARCHAR(50),
 5      IN `p_search` VARCHAR(50)
 6   )
    
 7   BEGIN
 8          Declare v_Query VARCHAR(4000); 
 9          set v_Query='';
 10         set v_Query='SELECT CONCAT(u.firstname, '''', u.lastname) as group_name FROM  users u ;
            
11          IF (p_criteria IS NOT NULL AND p_criteria='name') THEN
12              set v_Query=CONCAT(v_Query , ' WHERE lower(u.firstname)');
13              set v_Query=CONCAT(v_Query , ' LIKE  LOWER (''%@p_search%'')' ) ;
14          END if;
            
15          insert into testsql(qry)VALUES(CONCAT('q=' , v_Query));             
    
            COMMIT;
            SET @result_set = CONCAT(v_query, ' ');
            PREPARE statement FROM @result_set ;
            EXECUTE statement;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE statement;
    END$$
    DELIMITER ;
```

I tried above store procedure, and it generates select query as below in line no 15.

```
SELECT CONCAT(u.firstname, '', u.lastname) as group_name FROM  users u WHERE lower(u.firstname) LIKE  LOWER ('%@p_search%')
```

Actually I want the parameter which passing in clause to be in lower function.

```
SELECT CONCAT(u.firstname, '', u.lastname) as group_name FROM  users u WHERE lower(u.firstname) LIKE  LOWER ('%peter%')
```

Comment: I can't be bothered with escape sequences(ie can't remember them) so use ascii codes instead ' LIKE  LOWER (',char(39),char(38),p_search,char(38),char(39),')'